# Effective field theory of massive spin-1 and spin-2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, scattering, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

I'd like to understand what could be the use of an effective field theory (EFT) of a single massive particle of spin 1 or 2, or simple modification of these (see below). By EFT, I mean the most general Lagrangian that can be written using a massive (Abelian or not) spin-1 field $A_\mu$ or spin-2 field $h_{\mu\nu}$, including all possible higher derivative terms. I only care about the $2\to2$ scattering of the associated particle, so the Lagrangian should only contain terms with 3 (vertexes) or 4 (contact terms) fields.

The question is the following. Is there some "physically relevant" theory whose effective low-energy description is given by the aforementioned Lagrangians? For example, QCD at low energies is described by the chiral Lagrangian, namely an EFT for massless scalars, the pions. In that case, there is a flavor symmetry structure for the group $U(N_f)$, and the terms of the Lagrangian are compatible with the symmetries of the theory. Something similar would also be fine for me: namely, some terms of the Lagrangian (i.e. Wilson coefficients) might vanish because of symmetry or other reasons. It would be great if some EFT coupling had a concrete connection with measurable quantities in high-energy experiments.

I have in mind some effective description of QCD or pure Yang-Mills theory, but I'm interest in everything: supersymmetric theories, Abelian (and non Abelian) gauge theories, anything would be useful. For example, in https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.05582 the authors mention that there is an effective description of pure Yang-Mills in terms of scalar fields (the effective Lagrangian is reported in equation 12): this case is rather trivial, because only two terms contribute for the $2\to2$ scattering of these scalars (the cubic and quartic pieces of the potential). See also Section 4.4.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.13009 for other examples in the massless (photon) context.

Two more remarks. The first is that sufficiently simple mixed cases are also fine for me. In other words, perhaps there is a physically interesting effective field theory of massive vectors plus a massless scalar, with a Lagrangian that couples them in infinite possible ways. Or a massive graviton plus a fermion. The second comment is that these theories do not necessarily need to come from some UV known theory. One famous instance is $\Lambda_3$ massive gravity theory (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04068), whose Lagrangian is in equation 2 with constraints in equation 5.